# How to initialize an angularJS factory with a button click

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory to load data from an API. Code looks like

```
.factory('iScroll', function($http) {
        var iScroll = function(pre_url){
            this.items = [];
            this.busy = false;
            this.page = 1;
            this.pre_url = pre_url;
        }
        iScroll.prototype.nextPage = function(){
            if(this.busy) return;
            this.busy = true;
            var url = this.pre_url + 'page='+this.page;
            $http.get(url).then(function(response){
                console.log(response.data); 
                for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
                    this.items.push(response.data[i]);
                    console.log("loading...");
                }
                this.page++;
                this.busy = false;
            }.bind(this));
        };
        return iScroll;
    })
```

I initialize it like `$scope.load_users = new iScroll('/api/web/branches/users/' +$stateParams.id+'?');`

My question is, how can i call the factory via a button click?

Comment: Are you asking how to use `ngClick`? There are plenty of resources for that: (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

Comment: Yes i mean how do i use a click event to trigger the factory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template, you would use the `ngClick` directive to trigger an action:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="loadUsersAction()">Load Users</button>
```

Then in your controller, you define that function:

```
$scope.loadUsersAction = function() {
  $scope.load_users = new iScroll('/api/web/branches/users/' +$stateParams.id+'?');
};
```